# Sequential instatiation of Verilog Modules

Tags: verilog, system-generator

I am trying to implement an algorithm on hardware(ZedBoard) which has multiple modules. There is a **top module** and I will instantiate all these multiple modules inside the **top module**.

Approximately there are **9 to 10 modules of which 3 has to run concurrently, rest has to run sequentially**.

(I know that all modules inside the top module run concurrently. This is okay with the 3 modules that have to run concurrently but what about the rest of the modules that have to run sequentially???) and also ( I came to know that we can't instantiate modules inside always or initial block which actually doesn't make sense)

> 1. Is there a way to instantiate modules so that they run sequentially(like one after the other)????
> 2. Also, Is there a way to instantiate modules so that they run conditionally????
> 3. Can this be achieved using the system generator????

*fyi: I am using Verilog HDL and the code should be synthesizable*

Comment: I think you should work on your terminology (which is probably because you approach HDL as a standard computer language.)  In HDL **all** instantiated code runs concurrently.  Sequentially and/or parallel operation depend on how you **connect** the modules, or to be more precise. how you organize/connect the data paths. You can have e.g. one module which processes multiple data paths in parallel. Or one module which performs multiple operations on one data stream sequentially.

Answer (score 0):

Verilog describes hardware behavior. All hardware elements are parallel by nature. Therefore all elemens in verilog are simulated in parallel manner to mimic hardware behavior.

Data in the model can flow sequentially or parllel, dependig on your connections. If your applay data to the input or an element, the element will process the data and update its outputs. Elements which are their inputs connected to the output of the first element will process their inputs and update outputs, and so on. You can think of it as a net of pipes.

To synchronize data flow across different elements there are clocks, which drive flops and latches.

Basically the above defines your verilog model.

In other words, verilog is not a regular programming language therfore,

1) there is only a single way to instatiate the modules: connect them to other modules and internal wires.

2) there is no way to conditionally run or not run the module. You can have hardware elements, like muxes, latches, ... which can stop or re-route data flow. Fortunately behavior verilog can describe those with 'if' or 'case' statements.

3) you cannot achieve the impossible with any generator.